# Advanced javascript sourced data - DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The [default way](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) of initializing dataTables with javascript sourced data is with the [data option](http://datatables.net/reference/option/data) and it accepts either an array of arrays or an array of objects as far as I know.

```
var arrayDataSet = [
    ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 11', '11'],
    ['Blink', 'Chrome 35', '35'],
    ...
];

var objectDataSet = [
    {
        engine: 'Trident',
        browser: 'Internet Explorer 11',
        version: '11'
    },
    {
        engine: 'Blink',
        browser: 'Chrome 35',
        version: '35'
    }
    ...
];
```

I want to use the [createdRow](http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option though and add for example an id and url on each row. I think I want to initialize with data like this instead:

```
var otherDataSet = [
    {
        id: 'ie11',
        url: 'http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie',
        data: {
            engine: 'Trident',
            browser: 'Internet Explorer 11',
            version: '11'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'chr35',
        url: 'https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/',
        data: {
            engine: 'Blink',
            browser: 'Chrome 35',
            version: '35'
        }
    }
];
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this can be done. You need to set the data property in the columns config object to set where each column should use for it's data. Then you can reference any other fields in the `createdRow` callback. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7bBg/2/

```
var otherDataSet = [
    {
        id: 'ie11',
        url: 'http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie',
        data: {
            engine: 'Trident',
            browser: 'Internet Explorer 11',
            version: '11'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'chr35',
        url: 'https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/',
        data: {
            engine: 'Blink',
            browser: 'Chrome 35',
            version: '35'
        }
    }
];


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": otherDataSet,

        //define the columns and set the data property for each column
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine",  "data": "data.engine" },
            { "title": "Browser", "data": "data.browser"},
            { "title": "Version", "data": "data.version"}
        ],
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
            //adding id and url as attributes to the row
            $(row).attr('id',data.id).attr('data-url',data.url);
        }
    } );            
});
```