# How do I get DataTable data to load my JSON without the AJAX call?

Tags: asp.net, datatables

I am working with DataTables, trying to load my json data.  The HTML renders fine but I can't get any data to display.  The live data wasn't working so I created a string to simulate the return.  I'm not making an Ajax call to get the data, I'm calling the endpoint in c# and passing the resulting json string to JS.  I'm getting no errors in the console.  If you are curious why I'm not using Ajax, I'll say I don't know. :-)

We just downloaded DataTables so it is the latest version and the project is .Net Framework 4.6.1

Here is my Json:

```
    var fakeJson =
         {
             "data":
             {
                 "Triggers": {
                     "TriggerTypeId": 2,
                     "TriggeredKeyId1": 499,
                     "TriggerHelpText": "Blah blah blah",
                     "TriggerActionDefinitionID": 2,
                     "ComparisonOperatorID": 1
                 },
                 "Action": {
                     "TaDescription":"this is an action description"
                 },
                 "Protocols": {
                     "protocolDescription": "this is a protocol description"
                 },
                 "Operators": {
                     "CODisplayText": "="
                 }
             }
         };
```

and here is my JS:

```
         var dataSource = <%= DataTableJson %>;
         dataString = JSON.stringify(dataSource);
         dataSource = JSON.parse(dataString);

         console.log(fakeJson.data.Triggers.TriggerHelpText);

        var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
            table: '#ProtocolTriggerTable',
            "data": fakeJson
            },

            fields: [{
                label: "Comparison",
                name: "data.Operators.CODisplayText",
                //type: "select"
             }, {
                label: "Action",
                name: "data.Action.TaDescription",
                //type: "select"
            }, {
                label: "Item",
                name: "data.Protocols.protocolDescription",
                //type: "select"
            }, {
                label: "Pop-up Text",
                    name: "data.Triggers.TriggerHelpText",
                //type: "select"
            }]
        });

         $('#ProtocolTriggerTable').DataTable({
             dom: "rt",
             data: fakeJson,
             columns: [
                 { data: "data.Operators.CODisplayText" },
                 { data: "data.Action.TaDescription" },
                 { data: "data.Protocols.protocolDescription" },
                 { data: "data.Triggers.TriggerHelpText" }
             ],

         });
```

and the HTML

```
<table border="1" id="ProtocolTriggerTable" class="display" style="background-color: #e0e0e0; width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:20px !important"></th> 
            <th>Comparison</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Pop-up Text</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Follow-up:** Based on two or three good comments below, here is the Json structure that finally worked.  No I just have to apply this to my live data.

```
        var fakeJson =
            [{
                "Triggers": {
                    "TriggerTypeId": 2,
                    "TriggeredKeyId1": 499,
                    "TriggerHelpText": "Blah blah blah",
                    "TriggerActionDefinitionID": 2,
                    "ComparisonOperatorID": 1
                },
                "Action": {
                    "TaDescription": "this is an action description"
                },
                "Protocols": {
                    "protocolDescription": "this is a protocol description"
                },
                "Operators": {
                    "CODisplayText": "="
                }
            }];
```

Comment: Your JSON data does not contain an array. Datatables expects an array of arrays or an array of objects. See the documentation for the [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option. The array is important - that is what DataTables iterates over for you, to create each row in the table. You may need to "help" DataTables by pointing the `data` option at where the array is located in your JSON. For example, `data: "fakeJson.data` - assuming the array is at `"data": [ ... ]`.

Comment: I expect if you fix your JSON and get the `data` option to work, you can revisit using Ajax. Probably a similar root problem. See also [When using Ajax with jQuery DataTables, how do I determine what to do with the data returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64944852/12567365)

Comment: Is DataTableJson=fakeJson or what? I dont see DataTableJson defined

Comment: Related: [Advanced javascript sourced data - DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24584769/12567365)

Comment: @andrewJames you should have posted this as the answer.

Comment: Ha - thank you for the note. It's a duplicate question, in my opinion, though. It's more "the SO way" to use this as a pointer to an existing answer rather than accept an answer which is not really a new answer (in my opinion). Alternatively you could have [self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and you could have moved your edit from your question into your own answer.

Comment: (Also, the accepted answer here provides no explanations, for future visitors. Just a chunk of JSON - and not even an array of objects.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the DataTableJson is not usable try something like this:

```
[
    ['Comparison0', 'Action0', 'Item0', 'Popup0'],
    ['Comparison1', 'Action1', 'Item1', 'Popup1'],
]
```